# I want to insert a link href with target attribute in json object

Tags: html, json, reactjs, firebase

```
  ...

    "Social": [{
                    "href": "\"https://www.facebook.com/examplepage\" target:\"_blank\"",                       
                    "icon": "facebook",
                    "title": "Facebook"
                },
...
```

I want to open this facebook page into new tab.This is the part of json file which is going to import to firebase realtime database.This is a react web page there is a link inside a button to visit facebook by clicking the button.As you see above this code is part of the json will be import to firebase db,which is conneted to that react app.As per the above code once the button clicked the fb page opens in the same page.But I want to open this page in new tab.So My question I want to include target atttribute in a proper way.I tried above code but page is opening the same page

Comment: "Social": [{
                    "href": "https://www.facebook.com/examplepage",
                    "icon": "facebook",
                    "title": "Facebook"
                }, 
this is how my json file currently working.Link I have put into href should open in new tab ,can we cofigure that is here

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<Link {...Social[0]} >Your Link</Link>
```

The spread operator is the best way to dynamically assign attributes to your elements.

Comment: I want to insert it into json file .It should be a key-value pair.But your answer not look like that can you explain.

Comment: href link is correct  I made a mistake while I'm copying here.

Comment: I apologize I misunderstood your question. Here is the correct solution.

Comment: I believe he doesn't want to pass it as props and i quote from him "I want to insert it into json file"

Answer (score 1):

just add it like this

```
<button>
  <a href={`${Social[0].href}`} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
    Facebook
  </a>
</button>
```

and of course if this is an array you want to loop it

```
 YourJson['Social'].map(data => {
  return (
    // your jsx block which include the button
    <button>
      <a href={`${data.href}`} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
        {data.title}
      </a>
    </button>
  );
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by key-value pair format. you want and i quote "I want to open this facebook page into new tab" you can use this part as you want in map function or in simple jsx its the same concept. all you need is an href with target = "_blank"

Comment: this is the part of json file ,it's a real time firebase db i have to insert link.it's working but i have to open that in new tab..if i want to use in react jsx file its ok..but it's should be json file.

Comment: It's working now. I tried to put open in new tab condition inside firebase db json file..But now I understood it not a proper way.Then I have updated that logic in React page like above code.Now it's working fine.